# Variable inside paragraph in reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

Hi I'm working on reportlab. I want to add a variable inside a paragraph.

My variable is 'a'

```
a = 'Apple'

p = Paragraph("""This is <var> a <\var>"""style=None)
```

My expected output is `This is Apple`
but this doesn't work.

Comment: `p = Paragraph("""This is {a}"""style=None) `
is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Not working. I want that word 'Apple' in between paragraph.

Comment: Why isn't there a comma at `style=None `?

Comment: I missed here but its present in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.6 and above, you could try f-strings:

```
p = Paragraph(f"""This is {a}""", style=None)
```